# flat file database system especially for javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, couchdb, flat-file, database

Is there any flat file database system that works well with javascript such as one in JSON format or similar. I have heard about **mongodb**, **couchdb** and others but it seems whole setup of it must be installed on the computer.

Of course,  I can't use `sqlite` beause I think I won't be able manipulate it via javascript and I don't want to use any server-side language for my small apps.

I searched on google as well. Basically I am just looking for flat file database system that I can put in javascript app's folder (meaning portable database and app) and be able to use it anywhere, for example on some other computer without having to install any dependencies ? Does such portable flat file database exist out there ?

Comment: Since JS has a hard time using the local file system, perhaps localstorage suits your needs, assuming you are talking client side JS

Comment: @mplungjan: True but LocalStorage is way small in size that's why looking if there is some other portable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)? It's intended for web apps that cache data offline.